# What is meant by backtrace in php why we use debug_backtrace() and debug_print_backtrace() functions in php?

Tags: php, error-handling, backtrace, debug-backtrace

I am new to php and learning it from **php.net** and currently I am reading about debugging using [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

Can anyone tell me what is meant by **backtrace** and why we use **debug_backtrace()** and **debug_print_backtrace()** functions in php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP backtrace family of functions let you understand how the functions have been called in the particular request.

For example if you have called function `foo()` before function `bar()`, then if you write debug print backtrace in `bar()` function then you will see `foo()` has been called before `bar()` function. This also provides you what arguments you have passed to `bar()` function.

This helps you to trace back where and what functions are called to reach the current line of code (where you have written the backtrace function)

Comment: But what is backtrace ?

Comment: Its tracing back the function calls for that program.

Answer (score 1):

The debug_backtrace() is a function which generates a PHP backtrace(similar to python stack traceback).

This **function displays data from the code that led up to the debug_backtrace() function** and Returns an array of associative arrays

since you are new instead of  http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php
you can visit https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_error_debug_backtrace.asp

Comment: But what is backtrace ?

Comment: backtrace is also known as stack trace ,
A stack trace allows tracking the sequence of nested functions called - up to the point where the stack trace is generated. ie., it traces data from the code that led up to the debug_backtrace() function